# Compare the classes of 2 separate JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, comparison, class-design

I want to compare the classes of 2 JavaScript objects.  The current call below fails.  The idea here is to deal extract the correct cross-rate using the passed-in "from and to" variables.

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATED: The Working Code Now Looks Like This:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    // ------------------------
    // CLASS
    function Currency(clientId, country, code, imageURL, name) {

        this.clientId = clientId            //EXAMPLE: txtBudget
        this.country = country;             //EXAMPLE: America
        this.code = code;                   //EXAMPLE: USD
        this.imageURL = imageURL;           //EXAMPLE: "http://someplace/mySymbol.gif"
        this.name = name;                   //EXAMPLE: Dollar
        this.amount = parseFloat("0.00");   //EXAMPLE: 100
    };
    Currency.prototype.convertFrom = function (currency, factor) {
        this.amount = currency.amount * factor;
    }

    // CLASS
    function Pound(clientId, imageURL) {
        Currency.call(this, clientId, "Greate Britain", "GBP", imageURL, "Pound");
    };
    Pound.prototype = new Currency();
    Pound.prototype.constructor = Pound;

    // CLASS
    function Dollar(clientId, imageURL) {
        Currency.call(this, clientId, "America", "USD", imageURL, "Dollar");
    };
    Dollar.prototype = new Currency();
    Dollar.prototype.constructor = Dollar;

    // CLASS
    function Reais(clientId, imageURL) {
        Currency.call(this, clientId, "Brazil", "BRL", imageURL, "Reais");
    };
    Reais.prototype = new Currency();
    Reais.prototype.constructor = Reais;

    // ------------------------
    // CLASS
    function Suscriber(element) {
        this.element = element;
    };
    // CLASS
    function Publisher() {
        this.subscribers = new Array();
        this.currencyCrossRates = new Array();
    };
    Publisher.prototype.findCrossRate = function (from, to) {
        var crossRate = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.currencyCrossRates.length; i++) {
            if ((this.currencyCrossRates[i].from.constructor === from.constructor) && (this.currencyCrossRates[i].to.constructor === to.constructor))
                crossRate = this.currencyCrossRates[i];
        }
        return crossRate;
    }

    // ------------------------
    // CLASS
    function CurrencyCrossRate(from, to, rate) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.rate = parseFloat(rate);
    };

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        var dollar = new Dollar(null, null);
        var reais = new Reais(null, null);

        var dollarToReais = new CurrencyCrossRate(dollar, reais, 0.8);
        var reaisToDollar = new CurrencyCrossRate(reais, dollar, 1.2);

        publisher = new Publisher();
        publisher.currencyCrossRates.push(dollarToReais);
        publisher.currencyCrossRates.push(reaisToDollar);

        // SETUP
        jQuery(".currency").each(function () {
            publisher.subscribers.push(new Suscriber(this));
        });

        var newDollar = new Dollar(null, null);
        var newReais = new Reais(null, null);

        // This now resolves correctly
        var first = crossRate = publisher.findCrossRate(newDollar, newReais);
        var second = crossRate = publisher.findCrossRate(newReais, newDollar);
    });
-->
</script>
```

Comment: instanceof should work. What do you mean by compare?

Comment: I mean to compare the crossRate.from instance to the passed-in instance.

Comment: Try changing prototype to constructor in your comparisons

Comment: Ah ok. Joey is right, you need to do `from instanceof rates[i].from.constructor`

Comment: UPDATED! It still fails so I posted the whole thing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Inspecting the class at runtime sounds very fishy. Can't you just give your objects a polymorphoic methid instead?

Comment: @Missingno I added the alerts above to show why it should work.  In the meantime, can you provide an example of a polymorphic JavaScript method?

Comment: Just a normal method. Instead of doing `function foo(x){ //do stuff depending on the class of x here` you do `x.foo()` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right hand side operator of `instanceof` should not be the prototype object, but instead the object's constructor function, accessible through the `constructor` property of the object in question. Since this property in fact references *the* function which was used to construct the object, comparison is done with the usual equality operator:

```
this.currencyCrossRates[i].from.constructor == from.constructor
```

EDIT:

1. Remove the lines `Pound.prototype.constructor = Pound();` etc (one for each currency). The `constructor` property is a built-in feature which automatically references the correct function. However, it *is* unfortunately writable and so can be reassigned - don't do it!
2. The conditions should be of the form `this.currencyCrossRates[i].from instanceof from.constructor` - the left operand is the Object and the right one is the constructor *function*.

Comment: UPDATED! It still fails so I posted the whole thing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I "think" I MUST to overwrite the "Pound.prototype.constructor" because the Currency base-class assignment?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right, it seems. So you want the assignment to be `Pound.prototype.constructor = Pound;` instead, without the `()`.

Comment: @Prisoner ZERO: You're most welcome, and thanks yourself - I learned a thing or two here myself!